# cancancan create permission not working properly with conditions hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cancancan

I want admin User to be able to create new users for this account and read, update users from this account.

```
can [:create, :read, :update], User, id: account_users_ids
```

is not working if account_users_ids is not en empty array.
I need to split permissions to get it working

```
can :create, User
can [:read, :update], User, id: account_users_ids
```

what is wrong with defining conditions as

```
can [:create, :read, :update], User, id: account_user_ids
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a little late, but in Ruby 2.0+ your hash of conditions is interpreted as a keyword argument, which CanCanCan ignores in this instance.

Adding brackets should allow this to work as expected:

`can [:create, :read, :update], User, { id: account_user_ids }`

See also:

Keyword Args: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments

`CanCan::Ability#can`: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/lib/cancan/ability.rb#L132-L134